# When I move the slide deck activation code into an Initialize file it stops working why is that?

Tags: jquery

I am creating a site and would like to keep my HTML separate from my JS. I have created a plug-ins.js file to place all my jquery plug-ins. I have also created a script file called scripts.js to place all the scripts I have written for the site as well as to place all Initialization commands and settings for the given plug-in.

I am currently starting out with just one plug-in: a slide deck I have placed the plug-ins script into the plug-ins file but I am unable to place the Initialize command into the script file because when I do it stops working. The Initialize command for the slide deck is currently placed in line 127 of my HTML document.

URL TO LIVE DEMO: http://epecho.com/tst/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the slidedeck like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.slidedeck').slidedeck();
});
```

Comment: It is place in a document ready function block. It dose not work.